# Group numbers in a list by their indices (python0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this group of numbers:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and I have their indices grouped like this:

```
indices = [[0],[1,2],[3,4,5]]
```

I want to group the numbers in list 'a' in the way how their indices are grouped to get something like this:

```
b= [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
indices = [[0],[1,2],[3,4,5]]

result = [[a[index] for index in index_list] for index_list in indices]
```

Comment: beat me for a second, GJ

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `itemgetter()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
indices = [[0],[1,2],[3,4,5]]

[list(itemgetter(*i)(a)) if len(i) > 1 else [itemgetter(*i)(a)]
                                              for i in indices]
#  [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```